# Which player is responsible for completing a pawn promotion in tournament-level chess?

Tags: chess

Given that players want to conserve their clock time, which player is responsible for placing a pawn-promoted piece on the board, is it the pawn-promoter or the opponent? Related: is there a rule about where captured pieces must be placed during the game?

Answer (score 8):

From the [official laws of chess](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=208&view=article):

> 3.7.5.1 When a player, having the move, plays a pawn to the rank furthest from its starting position, **he must exchange that pawn as part of the same move** for a new queen, rook, bishop or knight of the same colour on the intended square of arrival. This is called the square of ‘promotion’.

(emphasis mine)

Of captures, nothing is said apart from

> 3.1.1 If a piece moves to a square occupied by an opponent’s piece the latter is captured and removed from the chessboard as part of the same move.

In practice, any place on the table where it does not hinder either player is fine, e.g. you shouldn't put them in front of or even on the clock.

Comment: That makes sense. I could just see complaints arising if the opponent were to hoard captured pieces and took his or her time about putting the new piece on the board! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Jeff If the opponent didn't give the piece immediately, you should stop the clock and call the arbiter.